# Splitting a list of duplicated items

Tags: c#

So, I have a list of duplicated items in `c#`. My problem is slightly more complicated than this, but a search has resulted in very specific solutions. I am looking for help on a more general level.

My main List contains

```
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 3,
Item 3,
Item 4,
Item 4,
Item 5,
Item 5,
Item 6,
Item 6,
```

I need to split this into two lists like so....

**List 1.....**

```
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 3,
Item 4,
Item 5,
Item 6,
```

**List 2.....**

```
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 3,
Item 4,
Item 5,
Item 6,
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are these items specific objects, how do we know the difference between `Item 1` and the next `Item 1`? TBH, if this is your concern, why are you *allowing* the duplicates to go in there; create seperate lists and handle that *if you can*. Please update your post to *include what you have tried* and what isn't working.

Comment: Does order of items stay the same all the time, in other words will you have situation, for example: Item1, Item2, Item1, Item3, Item3, Item2

Comment: What are the types of items? Are they string?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. Be sure to specify the inputs **in code** as well as be super clear about the expected outputs. Be sure to include some items in the input which are there once, some twice and some three times.

Comment: Can you be more specific? As described, you could build list 1 by selecting the distinct items from your main list, and building your second list by making a deep copy of the first list. Is the main list sorted, what makes the two `item1`s both have item1-ness? What happens if there is only one instance of an item in the main list?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Item 1 and the next Item 1 are different instances of the same object

Comment: Ok, so it *doesn't matter which list either of these go into* then?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to generate N lists, where N is the largest number of duplicates in your original list. In that case consider this approach. Iterate over the original list (`foreach`). Add entries to a `HashSet` - if the `Add` fails (returns `false`), add it to a second list. Once done - convert the `HashSet` to a `List` using `ToList`. Boom. That is your first list. Now, start the process again using your second list as the original list. Repeat the process until the list is empty.

Comment: Çöđěxěŕ no it doesn't matter

Comment: Darjan Bogdan the order can be random

Comment: @Monty if they are different instances, then how do I know to put this item in list one and this one in another list; specifically what part of *this* object can we use to determine this, otherwise there's no condition. You did mention that the order can be random, but this alone doesn't negate who belongs where...

Comment: Well thanks for you help guys, as I said the problem is more complicated than I have described, I tried to avoid complicating the question with irrelevant constraints... there are a number of conditions that need to be satisfied and this is pivotal in ensuring that that happens.... I'll have to work on the Question I think.....

Comment: By not saying what the problem is, you are preventing us from offering valid advice. My silly solution matches your specs. A sentence like "Item 1 and the next Item 1 are different instances of the same object" is meaningless. If they represent the same object, then they are the same instance (even if you added them to the same list through different variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `GroupBy`: we group initial `listWithDuplicates` into groups (so all duplicates now in their own chunks)

```
List<MyItem> listWithDuplicates = ...

//TODO: You may want to put custom criterium here, e.g. 
//  .GroupBy(item => item.Id);
var groups = listWithDuplicates
  .GroupBy(item => item); 

List<List<MyItem>> allLists = new List<List<MyItem>>();

foreach (var group in groups) {
  int index = 0;

  foreach (var item in group) {
    List<MyItem> list;

    if (allLists.Count > index)
      list = allLists[index];
    else {
      list = new List<MyItem>();
      allLists.Add(list);  
    }

    list.Add(item); 

    index += 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a `Dictionary<string,int>` object to store the count of duplicate values for each of the string object. For example, if "Item1" repeats 4 times, "Item2" repeats 2 times and so on.. you can reference it in your dictionary object.
Based on that you can create a number of lists which you require.
Following is the code for adding it in the dictionary

```
 List<String> l = new List<string>(){
//your items here
};
Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(string i in l)
{
if (!map.ContainsKey(i)) { map.Add(i, 0); }
else{
  map[i] =map[i] + 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: `GroupBy` could be used to simplify this. Also, `Add` doesn't work if the key is already there. Also consider using `TryGetValue` to avoid an unnecessary hash lookup.

Comment: updated the logic.

Comment: @mjwills, Agree with you. this is just another approach. The key takeaway from the answer is to use a map and then process the logic.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ as we are not sure in the input about number of repetitions of each item in the list. Dictionary (or a hashmap in Java) can be helpful to store the number of times each item occurs and based on the largest occurring item, user can then process his logic to create as many lists as he wants. map becomes a centralized place for all items and is a constant time operation

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. I dont like LINQ for this problem personally. Here is my solution. I have considered the items as integers, but it could be adapted to any type you would just have to update the equality check for that. This will make n lists where n is the number of duplicates (for example, if 4 occurs 3 times it will make 3 lists)

```
        List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
        int lastValue = 0;
        int countOfCurrent = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int value = list[i];

            if(value == lastValue && i > 0)
            {
                countOfCurrent++;
            } else
            {
                countOfCurrent = 0;
            }

            if(countOfCurrent >= lists.Count)
            {
                lists.Add(new List<int> { value });
            } else
            {
                lists[countOfCurrent].Add(value);
            }

            lastValue = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming strings in list:

```
var listOne = new List<string>();
var listTwo = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in listWithDuplicats)
            {
                if (!listOne.Contains(item))
                {
                    listOne.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    listTwo.Add(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What if it is there three times?

Comment: Yes i should have mentioned that... there could be many lists

Comment: @andreasnico if this is your idea of `KISS` it's wrong TBH. Your example *maybe* simple, but the problem is it's not correct as it doesn't fulfill the OP requirements.. Also it helps if you could explain *why* your `KISS` example would work.